# Issue with django at runserver command

Tags: django

im new in django and i have suposedly a really simple issue which is driving me crazy.

once i create superuser and hit the runserver command i go to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ enter acc and pass and server throws me out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KHx7.png)
on random basis i sucseed in entering the admin panel, but once i get in and press anything it again throws me out and i see the below message
enter image description here

any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: what do you see in your console?

Comment: Show us your admin.py and the exact error what you got in your cmd prompt

Comment: this is now my cmd looks like .snipboard.io/MIhTXL.jpg
1. create superuser
   -add username
   -add pass
2. py manage.py runserver 

    - go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (working)

    - go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ sometimes its working and some times its  not working.
Here is now error looks like https://snipboard.io/JKTrUR.jpg here is what i see in the cmd https://snipboard.io/QlTOWf.jpg. 

Even stranger for me is that when if first run the server and it kicks me out i have to restart the browser to be able to open it again.

Comment: - same issue with different browser https://snipboard.io/eTf6t9.jpg
   - here is a pip freeze as well https://snipboard.io/jqtKEH.jpg
im not seing any particular that may show me whats wrong